# Como exibir uma imagem salva em outra pasta do projeto no vue?

Tags: imagem, vue.js, vuetify

Estou precisando exibir uma imagem que está salva em outra pasta do meu projeto dentro de uma tag v-img, no vuetify. Só que não tô conseguindo. Alguém sabe como fazer?

As minhas pastas do projeto estão assim organizadas:

```
►node_modules
►public
▼src
   ▼components
      ░GameCardField.vue
   ▼assets
      ▼cartas
         ░asdeouros.png
         ░doisdeouros.png
         ░tresdeouros.png
         ░quatrodeouros.png
```

Como importar essas imagens e exibi-las numa tag v-img dentro do arquivo do GameCardField.vue?

É possível eu criar um array, vazio, depois adicionar objetos em que, dentro desses objetos, contenha um atributo em que seu valor é o caminho para essas imagens, é possível exibir esses objetos pelo valor desse atributo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

você está dentro da pasta **components**, logo precisará ter **'../'** para sair dessa pasta e ficar em **src**, após isso é preciso entrar em **assets**, então temos **'../assets/'** e aí entramos em **cartas** e colocamos o nome da imagem, então teremos o seguinte caminho: **'../assets/cartas/nomeDaImagem.png'**.
Em relação ao Vuetify, o seu v-img basicamente vai ser:

```
 <v-img src="../assets/cartas/nomeDaImagem.png" ></v-img>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você possa fazer desse modo:

```
<v-img :src="require('@/assets/cartas/asdeouros.png')" />
```